# Directives in AngularJs 1.x: isolated scope vs require ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've always been using isolated scope in my directives in Angular 1.x. However, I came across a directive that just used `ngModel`. Now, I've seen there are some issues when using both (I know it's possible, sort of?).

Anyways, my question is, what are the major differences when using isolated scope and requiring `ngModel`?

I did an example and based on this, I don't see any differences? The example is available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ExGcigFz369QXxvYWOZR?p=preview

So, any kind of explanation is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With the isolated scope, you can also use '@', '&' and in angular 1.5s component '<' for one time binding to get better performance if you don't need two-way binding.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that, although, shouldn't it be '=' instead of '<'?

Comment: No. In angular 1.5 you can use .component, and use '<' for input data. As documentation says: Inputs should be using < and @ bindings. The < symbol denotes one-way bindings which are available since 1.5. The difference to = is that the bound properties in the component scope are not watched, which means if you assign a new value to the property in the component scope... https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component